# Google maps Force Closes when loading overlays Asyc

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Basically I have a maps Activity that when started it starts up a thread that slowly loads in all of the map markers (overlays).

Sometimes (probably like 75% of the time) when you attempt to interact with the map while this thread is running, it throws a RuntimeException with message "sending message to a handler on a dead thread".  I have concluded that this error is not thrown if you wait to interact with the map until after the thread is done.

So my initial questions are: does the maps API have known threading errors?  Is there a specific way one needs to go about loading maps data asynchronously?  Maybe there is some notify method I need to be calling?

Basically if I run the thread but comment this line:

```
mv.getOverlays().add(pin);
```

The thread runs like normal but does not add overlays, and the app does not crash.

I will show more code if we need it.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you creating a whole overlay for each pin?

Comment: I am actually not.  The variable 'pin' should actually be 'pins'.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at using an AsyncTask.  Here's some good background information on the subject: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html